# Hilbert series of tensor product of quotient ring by squarefree monomial ideals

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, hilbert-polynomial

Let $R=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a polynomial ring and $I,J$ be two distinct *squarefree monomial* ideals of $R$.

It is known that the Hilbert series of $R/I\otimes_K R/J$ is equal to the product of Hilbert series of $R/I$ and $R/J$, that is, $$HS(R/I\otimes_K R/J)=HS(R/I)HS(R/J).$$

In general, it is not true that $$HS(R/I\otimes_R R/J)=HS(R/I)HS(R/J).$$

Is it known a relation among the Hilbert series of $R/I\otimes_R R/J$, $R/I$ and $R/J$, where $I$ and $J$ are squarefree monomial ideals of $R=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$?

---

I did this example using a computational method, from which it is possible to find that the following formulas are not true in this case:

$$HS(R/I\otimes_R R/J)=\frac{HS(R/I)HS(R/J)}{HS(R)}$$

$$HS(R/I\otimes_R R/J)=HS(R/I)+HS(R/J)-HS(R/(I\cap J)$$

Remember that $R/I\otimes_R R/J$ is isomorphic to $R/(I+J)$. Consider $R=K[a,b,c,d,e]$ and $G=(ab,ac,ad,bd,ae)$.

i3 : reduceHilbert hilbertSeries G

```
               2    3           3
  ( 1 + 2T - 2T  + T ) / (1 - T)
```

Now we consider $I=(ab,ac,ad)$ and $J=(bd,ae)$, since $G=I+J$.

i5 : reduceHilbert hilbertSeries I

```
           2    3            4
 1 + T - 2T  + T  /   (1 - T)
```

i7 : reduceHilbert hilbertSeries J

```
           2          3
 1 + 2T + T  / (1 - T)
```

From the previous calculations we have $HS(R/I\otimes_R R/J)\neq \frac{HS(R/I)HS(R/J)}{HS(R)}$.

Consider $L=I\cap J$.

i9 : reduceHilbert hilbertSeries L

```
           2     3    4           4
  1 + T + T  - 3T  + T  /  (1 - T)
```

It follows that $HS(R/I\otimes_R R/J)\neq HS(R/I)+HS(R/J)-HS(R/(I\cap J)$.

Comment: Unless I’m mistaken $R/I \otimes_R R/J=R/(I+J)$, and there is an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow R/(I \cap J) \rightarrow R/I \oplus R/J \rightarrow R/(I+J) \rightarrow 0$, which shows $HS(R/I)+HS(R/J)=HS(R/I \otimes_R R/J)+HS(R/(I\cap J))$.

Comment: That's something to wrong... I did an example with Macaulay2 but I seems that the formula is not true, or maybe I made a mistake :(

Comment: I’m a bit surprised. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: I tried to do other examples and the formula $HS(R/I)+HS(R/J)=HS(R/I \otimes_R R/J)+HS(R/(I\cap J))$ is not true unfortunately. The isomorphic $R/I \otimes_R R/J=R/(I+J)$ is ok but I seem that the sequence is not exact :(

Comment: Hm… But how? The first map is injective, the last map is onto, and if $(a,b) \in R$ is such that $a-b \in I+J$, I want to show that $a \in c+I$, $b \in c+J$ for some $c \in R$. Well, let $a-b=i+j$, $i \in I,j \in J$. Then if $c=a-i=b+j$, $a=c+i \in c+I$, $b=c-j \in c+J$…

Comment: ok, you convinced me... but I still don't understand then where I went wrong with the Macaulay2. It seems to me that he gave all the correct commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general formula/fact:

> Proposition [(See Lemma 7 here)](http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1993__86_2_147_0.pdf): Let $k$ be a field, let $R$ be a positively graded $k$-algebra, and let $M$ and $N$ be graded $R$-modules. Suppose $M$ and $N$ have finite dimensional components and are nonzero in at most finitely many negative degrees. Then $$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^iHS(\operatorname{Tor}^R_i(M,N))=\dfrac{HS(M)HS(N)}{HS(R)}$$

Taking $M=R/I$ and $N=R/J$ and viewing them as graded $k$-vector spaces immediately recovers the formula
$$HS(R/I \otimes_k R/J)=HS(R/I)HS(R/J),$$ since $\operatorname{Tor}^k_i(M,N)=0$ whenever $i>0$ and since $HS(k)=1$.

Working over more general rings (e.g. $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$) instead, we will not have this $\operatorname{Tor}$-vanishing in general, so we cannot reduce the left hand side to $HS(R/I \otimes_R R/J)$.

As sketched in the comments, the formula $HS(R/I \otimes_R R/J)=HS(R/I)+HS(R/J)-HS(R/I \cap J)$ does hold. The example you computed with Macaulay2 evidences this as
$$\dfrac{1+2t-2t^2+t^3}{(1-t)^3}=\dfrac{1+t-2t^2+t^3}{(1-t)^4}+\dfrac{1+2t+t^2}{(1-t)^3}-\dfrac{1+t+t^2-3t^3+t^4}{(1-t)^4}$$